# How to realize SPI transfer during interrupt of kernel device driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt, spi

I have a linux master and a AD external device, they use SPI to communicate, when the external device can ben read, there will be an interrupt to master.
In the device driver, it seems the spi transfer function can't be use in the top half of the interrupt. To the bottom half, it seems the workqueue can use spi transfer function, so I realize the SPI transfer in the bottom half use workqueue, unfortunatly, when there are 7997 interrupts, there only 7907 data get. It can't solve my request.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhzjj.png)
Are there any methods to put the spi transfer step in the top half? or any other methods to make sure the number of spi transfer is same with interrupt number?

Comment: `spi_async()` can be used in interrupt contexts.

Comment: Sounds like you need to enable DMA.

Comment: Maybe you need a design where the interupts are limited to a rate that the transport can handle.